# redbean php создает новую строчку

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Недавно начал использовать RedBeanPHP, всё нормально работало, пока я не попытался сделать изменение логина.

```
<?php
require "db.php";
$data = $_POST;
if (isset($data['changelogin'])) {
    $errors = array();

    if (trim($data['oldlogin']) == '') {
        $errors[] = 'Введите старый логин';
    }

    if (trim($data['newlogin']) == '') {
        $errors[] = 'Введите новый логин';
    }
    $user = R::findOne('users', 'name = ?', array($data['oldlogin']));

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $users = R::load('users', $user);
        $users->name = $data['newlogin'];
        R::store($users);
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        echo '<div style="color: red;">' . array_shift($errors) . '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Вообщем, вместо того чтобы загружать новое имя, создается новая строка c почтой `NULL` Паролем `NULL`, но зато нужным логином.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас создается новая запись, потому что вы создаете нового пользователя и присваиваете ему только логин:

```
if (empty($errors)) {
    $users = R::load('users', $user);  // Загрузили юзера которого нет в базе $user = NULL;
    $user->name = $data['newlogin'];  // Присваиваем свойство name
    R::store($users); // Сохраняем нового юзера
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Вы уже загрузили модель юзера тут:

```
$user = R::findOne('users', 'name = ?', array($data['oldlogin']));
```

Все что вам нужно это изменить у него `name`:

```
$user->name = $data['newlogin'];
R::store('users', $user);
```

В итоге код будет такой:

```
<?php
require "db.php";
$data = $_POST;
if (isset($data['changelogin'])) {
    $errors = array();

    if (trim($data['oldlogin']) == '') {
        $errors[] = 'Введите старый логин';
    }

    if (trim($data['newlogin']) == '') {
        $errors[] = 'Введите новый логин';
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $user = R::findOne('users', 'name = ?', array($data['oldlogin']));
        $user->name = $data['newlogin'];
        R::store($user);
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        echo '<div style="color: red;">' . array_shift($errors) . '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Если ваша задача решена, можете закрыть вопрос)

Comment: Подождите теперь другая проблема (извините за то что туплю(я прост новичок в redbean)) Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\registernew\change-login.php on line 21 
```
Теперь такая проблема

Comment: Что на 21 строчке кода?

Comment: $users->name = $data['newlogin'];

Comment: Если не удобно могу вам прост отправить весь код

Comment: Посмотрите ответ, там была опечатка, должно быть ‘$user->name = $data[“newLogin”];’

Comment: Я Вас уже достал наверное.)))               Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\registernew\change-login.php on line 21

Comment: Помогити мне((((

Comment: @TarasOsyka , метод findOne, замените на fins

Comment: Вы уверены что есть такой метод ?

Comment: Извиняюсь, find

Comment: Давайте перейдём в личный чат, потому что теперь выдает                                   Attempt to assign property 'name' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\registernew\change-login.php on line 21